# Get-LocalUser in powershell fails with "The term 'Get-LocalUser' is not recognized"

Tags: powershell

I have installed both powershell binary and app image and get the same error in both. PSVersion:

```
    PSVersion                      6.1.0-preview.1
    PSEdition                      Core
    GitCommitId                    v6.1.0-preview.1
    OS                             Linux 4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu 
    SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018
    Platform                       Unix
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Running the cmdlet (or any related cmdlets gives the error)

> Get-LocalUser : The term 'Get-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1

```
    + Get-LocalUser
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Now I know that these tools are in the latest version of powershell or my reading has led me to believe that.  I also know it should be there so I am suspicious that either I am missing something from my environment or have erred in some way.  Any help would be appreciated. And yes, I have attempted to re-install, google, read the forums on MS and even the manuals on powershell but find nothing about this error only how to run the cmdlets.